# How to map entities with inheritance - Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core 2.0 project and I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.0
I want to map an entity that has an inheritance and this inheritance has an inheritance too

My entity which I want to map in `[Domain.Project]`:

```
public class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public Customer(Name name, DateTime? birthDay, Email email, string password, List<CreditDebitCard>  creditDebitCards = null)
    {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            Name = name;
            BirthDay = birthDay;
            Email = email;
            Password = password;
            _CreditDebitCards = creditDebitCards ?? new List<CreditDebitCard>();
    }

    [Fields...]
    [Properties...]
    [Methods...]
}
```

My `BaseEntity` class in `[Domain.Project]`:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : Notifiable
{
    public BaseEntity()
    {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            IsActive = true;
    }

    [Fields...]
    [Properties...]
    [Methods...]
}
```

My `Notifiable` class (look, it have a list of `Notification` type) in `[Shared.Project]`:

```
public abstract class Notifiable
{
    private readonly List<Notification> _notifications;

    protected Notifiable() { _notifications = new List<Notification>(); }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Notification> Notifications => _notifications;
    [Methods...]
}
```

My `Notification` class in `[Shared.Project]`:

```
public class Notification
{
    public Notification(string property, string message)
    {
        Property = property;
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Property { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
}
```

My Entity Framework context class in `[Infra.Project]`:

```
public class MoFomeDataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Runtime.ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CreditDebitCard>().Map();
    }
}
```

My `Mapping` class in `[Infra.Project]`:

```
public static class CustomerMap
{ 
    public static EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> cfg)
    {
        cfg.ToTable("Customer");
        cfg.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        cfg.Property(x => x.BirthDay).IsRequired();
        cfg.OwnsOne(x => x.Email);
        cfg.OwnsOne(x => x.Name);
        cfg.HasMany(x => x.CreditDebitCards);

        return cfg;
    }
}
```

When I try add a migration, I get this error:

> The entity type 'Notification' requires a primary key to be defined.

But neither the `Notification` class and neither the `Notifiable` class have been mapped in my context, they must not be mapped.

I do it in .net full framework and it works [here](https://github.com/italojs/Test_FCamara_API/tree/master/src) is the .net full framework code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention EF Core discovers and maps *all properties* of the entity class and *all its base classes*. In your case, `Notifications` property is discovered and identified as *collection navigation property*, hence the element type `Notification` is mapped as entity.

It's because the default assumption is that the entity model represent a *store model*. The members representing non store attributes should be unmapped explicitly. To fix the issue, just add the following to your `OnModelCreating` override:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<Notification>();
```

**References:**

- [Including & Excluding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types)
- [Including & Excluding Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties)
- [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)